# how to setup the environment to debug the Restcomm-smsc source code

Tags: intellij-idea, restcomm, mobicents

can you please describe me how to setup a development environment with intellij IDEA for restcomm-smsc to debug run compile build and doing breakpoints etc.

i am using ubuntu 14.04.

i could run the smsc gateway from the binary package and do the simulator tests but when it comes to do some coding and debugging and building stuff, i cannot creat e the correct development environment for restcomm-smsc source code.

i really appreciate if you can guide me simply how to do it?

Thanks a lot

BR

Gokhan

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to debug application deployed on JBoss? If so you need to simply add/uncomment JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=$DEBUG_PORT,server=y,suspend=n" in run.sh/standalone.sh.
In intellij Run -> Edit Configurations -> Remote and provide jboss IP and port from JAVA_OPTS.